# Do deformations of isolated hypersurface singularity naturally induce deformations of their divisors?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, deformation-theory

Let $0 \in V =(f=0) \subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ be an affine variety with an isolated hypersurface singularity at the origin for $n \ge 3$. 
Let $0 \in D=(x=f=0) \subset V$ be a divisor with only isolated singularity $0$ where $x$ is one of local coordinate.
Let $T^1_V, T^1_{(V,D)}$ be the set of 1st order deformations of $V$ and a pair $(V,D)$. 
We can consider the forgetting map $T^1_{(V,D)} \rightarrow T^1_V$. I want to consider the other way, that is, $T^1_V \rightarrow T^1_{(V,D)}$.

For $\eta \in T^1_V$, we can consider a small deformation $ \mathcal{V} \subset \mathbb{C}^4 \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow \Delta^1$ of $V$ over a small disc $\Delta^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ induced by $\eta$. 
Set $\Gamma := (x=0)$. 
I can consider $\mathcal{D} := \Gamma \times \Delta^1 \cap \mathcal{V} \subset \mathcal{V}$ 
and this defines a deformation of $D$.

> **Question 1** Does this construct $T^1_V \rightarrow T^1_{(V,D)}$? 
>   If yes, is it $\mathbb{C}$-linear? 
>   **(Added)** This construction seems to be not well-defined.

Moreover, I want to know how this is induced by a sheaf homomorphism. 
By $n=\dim V \ge 3$, we have

$T^1_V \simeq H^1(V', \Theta_{V'}) \simeq H^1(V', \Omega^{n-1}_{V'}(-K_V'))$,

$T^1_{(V,D)} \simeq H^1(V', \Theta_{V'}(\log D')) \simeq 
H^1(V', \Omega_{V'}^{n-1} (\log D') (-K_{V'} -D')).$

We can consider an inclusion $\Omega^{n-1}_{V'} \hookrightarrow \Omega^{n-1}_{V'}(\log D'))$ 
and an isomorphism 
$O_{V'} \rightarrow O_{V'}(- D')$. Hence we have a homomorphism

$\Omega_{V'}^{n-1} (-K_{V'}) \rightarrow \Omega^{n-1}_{V'}(\log D')(-K_V' -D')$.

> **Question 2 (Changed)** Is the above homomorphism induce zero homomorphism?